# How to change Dynamic dropdown list to have different value for options?

Tags: php, jquery, database

In my dynamic dropdown list, how would I change the option value ='" + data[i].toLowerCase() +  to be a value of different column from database table? My PHP is returning two jsonencode values, "ID" and "Outcome."  JSQuery works when it is just "Outcome" return but not when both "ID" and "Outcome." I have tried.

```
 options += '"<option value ="+ value[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
```

Below is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $.getJSON("getOutcome.php", success = function(data, value)
{
var options = "";

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    options += '"<option value ="+ value[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
}

$("#slctOutcome").append(options);

$("#slctOutcome").change();  //<-Here
});

$("#slctOutcome").change(function()
{   
  $.getJSON("getProxies.php?outcome=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
{
    var options = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        options += "<option value ='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
    }

    $("#slctProxy").html("");
    $("#slctProxy").append(options);

});

});
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return in your values from php in json array so you can use it like data[i].id and data[i].outcome, Or you can use $ajax instead of $getJSON and you use the succes function to display result.